# How to TemplateBinding in Customized Control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my project, I customize Slider control. Please help me.

```
                                <Thumb x:Name="HorizontalThumb" Grid.Column="1" Margin="-1,-10,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="1" >
                                    <!--<Thumb.RenderTransform>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" ScaleX="30"/>
                                        </Thumb.RenderTransform>-->
                                    <Thumb.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Image Height="60" Width="110" IsHitTestVisible="True" Margin="-110,-10" Stretch="Fill" Source="/DiaDiemJSC;component/bluebutton.png" />
                                                <TextBlock FontFamily="Tahoma" x:Name="TextContent" Text="{TemplateBinding ContentSlider}" Margin="-110,-10" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Thumb.Template>
                                </Thumb>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I want TemplateBinding to TextBlock x:Name="TextContent". I tried unsuccessfully to.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: hi xyzzer !
How to bindingdata to textBlock (name = "textContent") ?

Comment: It is hard to help you with only the half of your control template.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting ContentSlider property via Binding, then TemplateBinding will not work.

But TemplateBinding is an abbreviation of

```
{Binding Path=ContentSlider, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i'm guessing right then you are trying to create a control template for a slider control, and want to have a TextBlock which shows the value of the slider. Inside the Thumb the sliders Value wasn't accessible so you need to use something like i did in this small code example. I added the Value property to the Thumbs DataContext with TemplateBinding and then used Binding on my TextBlock and that worked.

```
<Thumb x:Name="HorizontalThumb" Grid.Column="1" Height="12" Margin="0,22,0,50" Width="12" DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}">
                                    <Thumb.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <Canvas Background="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Height="12" Width="12">
                                                <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" Height="84" IsHitTestVisible="True" Canvas.Left="-24" Canvas.Top="-22" Width="60"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                                            </Canvas>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                </Thumb.Template>
                            </Thumb>
```

Comment: yeah! That is my idea !
but I can not put value on the TextBlock TemplateBinding! Please help me

Comment: @thongaduka updated my answer and this should work i tested it.